# Prove that if P(A|B) > P(A) then P(A|B^c) < P(A)

Tags: probability

I've been working on this for a while.  I've figured out how to do it by manipulating both sides of the inequality.  My teacher doesn't allow this and I'm trying to get a proof that only manipulates one side of the equation and then eventually comes to the other.  Thanks.

P(A|B) > P(A)

P(A∩B) > P(A)P(B)

P(A)-P(A∩B^c) > P(A)P(B)

P(A∩B^c) < P(A)-P(A)P(B)

P(A∩B^c) < P(A)[1-P(B)]

P(A∩B^c) < P(A)P(B^c)

P(A∩B^C)/P(B^c) < P(A)

P(A|B^c) < P(A)

This is how I did it manipulating both sides.

Comment: Perhaps if you edited your question to show how you did this "manipulating both sides of the inequality", we could help adapt this to one which "only manipulates one side of the equation"

Comment: Good point.  I did this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $P(B)$ and $P(B^c)$ are non-zero, your proof is fine.

I do not see a sensible way of manipulating one side of an inequality while simultaneously keep the other side the same and reversing the direction of the inequality.

An alternative approach might be to start with

$$P(A\mid B)P(B)+P(A\mid B^c)P(B^c) = P(A) = P(A)P(B)+P(A)P(B^c)$$

so $$[P(A\mid B)-P(A)]P(B)= [P(A)-P(A\mid B^c)]P(B^c)$$

and thus if $P(A\mid B)-P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are positive then so too are $P(A)-P(A\mid B^c)$ and $P(B^c)$ implying $$P(A\mid B^c) \lt P(A)$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that 
$$P(A) = P(B) \cdot P(A\mid B) + P(B^c)\cdot P(A\mid B^c)$$ a weighted average of $P(A\mid B)$ and $P(A\mid B^c)$. If one is $> P(A)$, the other must be $< P(A)$.